# How to get a list of mutable strings?

Tags: c#, string, reference

I have the following piece of code

```
  List<String> l = new List<String>();
  String s = "hello";
  l.Add(s);
  s = "world";
```

When I set up some breakpoints and go through the program, after executing the last line, the value in the list is still `hello` instead of `world`.

Shouldn't it equal `world` ? Isn't a string an object, and am I not just inserting a pointer into the list? Later on if I change the string to point to a different value ("world"), why is my list still referencing the old value?

How can I get my desired effect ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable so that won't work.  When you attempt to set into it, you actually drop the pointer to the old string and create a new one under the hood.

To get the desired effect, create a class that wraps a string:

```
public class SortOfMutableString
{
    public string Value {get;set;}

    public SortOfMutableString(string s)
    { 
        Value = s;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(SortOfMutableString s)
    {
        return s.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator SortOfMutableString(string s)
    {
        return new SortOfMutableString(s);
    }
}
```

And use this in your list.  Then references will point to the class, but you can contain the string value inside.  To make it even better, override `implicit` casting to and from string so you don't even need to see that you are talking to a `SortOfMutableString`.

Refer to Jon Skeet's answer for undoubtedly a very accurate explanation about string's in C#, I'm not even going to bother!

Alternative class names:

- PseudoMutableString
- ICantBelieveItsNotMutable
- HappyAndReferenceableString

Comment: I personally love ICantBelieveItsNotMutable, you need Fabio to be your spokesman.

Comment: Thanks, the class names are good :P Any way I can override the assignment (=) operator so that on `s = "world"` it assigns to the value property in the main class ?

Comment: Not the equal operator, but if you override implicit as I have above, it will achieve the same.

Comment: And by equal, I mean assignment operator! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're changing the `s` reference to refer to a different `String` instance.
Strings are immutable; it is impossible to change the existing instance that you added to the list.

Instead, you can create a mutable `StringHolder` class with a writable `String` property.

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't equal `world`. The value of the variable `s` is a reference. When you call `l.Add(s)`, that reference is passed *by value* to the list. So the list now contains a reference to the string "hello".

You now change the value of `s` to a reference to the string "world". That doesn't change the list at all.

It's important to distinguish between three very different concepts:

- A variable (which has a name and a value)
- A reference (a value which allows you to navigate to an object, or `null`)
- An object

So in particular, the list doesn't know anything about the *variable* `s` - it knows about the *value* which was passed into `Add`; that value *happened* to be the value of `s` at the time `Add` was called, that's all.

You may find these articles helpful:

- [Values and references](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [Parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks. So any way I can do something like this but with pass by reference instead by value ?

Comment: @Rafal: No - by the time the method call has finished, the `ref`-ness would have expired, effectively. You can't keep a handle to another variable beyond the scope of the method call.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are two different references involved.  One called `s` and one that's at `List[0]`.  When you say `l.Add(s)` you are setting the list reference to the same address as `s`, but then when you assign `s` to "world", then `s` will point to the new string, leaving `List[0]` pointing to the old string.

If you really want to do something like what you are asking, you'd need to wrap the string in another object that contains a string, so that `s` and `List[0]` both refer to that object, and then that object's reference to a string can change and both will see it.

```
 public class StringWrapper
 {
     public string TheString { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can do:

```
 var s = new StringWrapper { TheString = "Hello" };
 var l = new List<StringWrapper>();
 l.Add(s);
 s.TheString = "World";
```

And now `l[0].TheString` will be world too.  This works because in this case we are not changing the reference in List[0] or s, but they contents of the object referred to by s and List[0].

Answer (score 0):

A variable is an object *reference*, not an object itself. `s = "world"` says "make `s` refer to the string `"World"`) - it does not in any way affect the string `"hello"` that `s` was previously referring to. Furthermore, strings in C# are always immutable. You can, however, make the first list element (which currently refers to `"hello"`) refer to a different string: `l[0] = "world"`.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers here did a great job of saying why what you tried didnt' work, but you were looking for a solution for your desired effect. Wrap a string (property) inside of an object. Then you can change that string and it will be reflected in the collection.