# List that always holds current variables value. C#

Tags: c#, list, mutable

So I need a list (or similar data structure) that always holds the current value for a given variable, once it has been added. This is what currently occurs (in simpler/pseudo code):

```
intValue = 5;
intList.Add(intValue);

Print intList[0].toString();
```

Prints "5"

```
intValue++;
Print intList[0].toString();
```

Still Prints "5" when I want it to print intValue's new value, "6".

Basically the list needs to store a reference to intValue (I think that's the correct terminology) and not it's actual value. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is pretty similar to the following:

[How to get a list of mutable strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913435/how-to-get-a-list-of-mutable-strings)

Change the `SortOfMutableString` implementation in the accepted answer to store `int` values instead of `string` and you'll get the desired effect.

Also, check out Jon Skeet's answer there. This is very important to fully understand the consequences of such kind of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Its not something that could be done with changing type of the list. You might have to create your own reference type which will behave like `int`. In `.net` structures are't reference types so its impossible with them to get such behaviour like you need.

You have to realize that `int` you've added to your list is just copy, so any change done to source won't affect the copy.

Answer (score 3):

This is because in C#, `int` is a **value** type instead of **reference** type. When you write

```
intValue = 5;
intList.Add(intValue);
```

you add a **copy** to `intValue`, and not a reference to the variable itself. What you want is to add a reference to the variable `intValue` to `intList`. What you can do is wrap your `int` values in a class of you own (which is a reference type).

Comment: I think this answer is clearer than the other answer, but I think your comment about using `ref` is misleading, as that will only work for method parameters.

Comment: @Steve Okay, I'm kind of new to C# so I've misunderstood that concept. Should I remove that from my answer?

Comment: I think so. Everything before `, or use ref in some way` was perfect.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for posting an answer! It all comes back around. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you will need to store the reference instead of the value of the variables, you can store the pointers. You will need to use `unsafe` keyword to use pointers in C#.

```
  unsafe
  {
    int intVal=5;
    List<IntPtr> intList = new List<IntPtr> ( );
    intList.Add ( new IntPtr ( &intVal ) );
    MessageBox.Show ( ( *( ( int* ) ( intList[0].ToPointer ( ) ) ) ).ToString ( ) );
    intVal++;
    MessageBox.Show ( ( *( ( int* ) ( intList[0].ToPointer ( ) ) ) ).ToString ( ) );
  }
```